# Difference using joins or navigation properties in EF

Tags: sql, database, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am learning EF and I am trying to understand when to use which type of query.

For example this query:

```
From fe In Processes.Where(Function(process) CBool(process.Type = 21 And 
                                            process.State = 0 And
                                            process.VDat > #2017/01/01# And
                                            process.ProcessAdresses.Any(Function(adr) adr.AdrNr = "0201") And
                                            process.ProcessPorisitions.Any(Function(pp) pp.ArtID = 200)))
```

Will return all `processes` of `Type=21`, `State=0`, `Vdat>01.01.2017`, which have a `processAdress` with `AdrNr`=0201 and a `position` with an `ArtId`=200.
Here the navigation Properties are used and lazy loading has to be enabled. (I think, since the related data needs to get loaded, and it will when accessing the nav props)

Now I can express the same query using joins:

```
From fe In Processes.Where(
            Function(process) CBool(
                process.Art = 215 And
                process.State = 0 And
                process.VDat > #2017/01/01#))
     Join adr In ProcessAdresses.Where(
             Function(adr) adr.AdrNr = "020107")
         On fe.VID Equals vadr.VID
     Join pp In ProcessPorisitions.Where(
             Function(pp) pp.ArtID = 20004993)
         On fe.VID Equals vpos.VID
     Group  By fe Into Group
     Select fe
```

Here no nav props are used.

I was trying to measure/analyse performance using LinqPad but I only could see the difference in the created SQL Query, without effort...

So my questions are:

- What are the main differences of querying one way to querying the other way?
- Is there any rule to follow for when using one or the other?
- How can I mess performance in such cases or for SQL queries in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the main differences of querying one way to querying the other way?

Joins are harder to read and more error prone. EG does the second query return the same data as the first?

> Is there any rule to follow for when using one or the other?

Use navigation properties whenever you can.

> How can I mess performance in such cases or for SQL queries in general?

Incorrect joins can cause poor performance, and complex LINQ queries can cause unexpectedly-complex SQL.  Also Eager Loading too many related entities can cause expensive queries.

Comment: The last point doesn't address the join vs navigation properties question. Of course one can make overly complex queries by joins where navigation properties aren't even available, but that's a different question. And eager loading too many data is also perfectly possible with navigation properties.

Comment: Incorrect joins was the only one that related to the Navigation Property vs. Join question, as Navigation properties have the join columns pre-wired.  The others related to the "**or for SQL queries in general** part"

Comment: Making this question too broad. I liked the question, so I tried to narrow it down to the question in the title, ignoring this little part, instead of VTC as too broad. Also, incorrect joins should be fixed anyway, not because or performance.

Comment: Yes, my question was like @gertArnold said, focused in the join vs nav props question. So I should make use of nav props and lazy loading/eager loading when ever I can, if I understand it right. Then comes for me the question about perfomance and when-to-use lazy loading-vs-eager loading, but that's a differen question...

Answer (score 5):

> What are the main differences of querying one way to querying the other way?

One look at your code tells enough. Using navigation properties makes code easier to understand and better maintainable. Also, explicit joins are error prone. It's easy to join wrong ID properties (I've seen it happen). Finally, it causes repetitive code if you have more similar queries.

> Is there any rule to follow for when using one or the other?

There are *guidelines*. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is one of them. See above.

> How can I mess performance in such cases or for SQL queries in general?

This may be the only exception to the rule (guideline). Navigation properties to non-mandatory entities will be translated as outer joins. Outer joins may perform worse than inner joins. So when performance is critical *and* when null references should be filtered out of the end result you may resort to an explicit join statement, overriding the navigation property.

See also: [Don't use Linq's Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/).

Comment: Navigation properties also tend to result in a lot of nested queries, which in certain cases I'm finding can cause redundant joins which is costly. The best policy is probably to always review the generated SQL for every LINQ query you write.