# Linq performance issue with list inside list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am trying to do linq query, but it take too long, since there are a lot of record. Can anyone give me tips where to start optimize it? I am kinda stuck on this.

```cs
var u = context.OtherTranslations.Select(x => new CmsOtherTranslationsView
{
    Id = x.ID,
    TranslationCode = x.TranslationCode,
    LangValues = context.OtherTranslationsValues
                        .Where(row => row.OtherTranslationId == x.ID)
                        .Join(context.Languages, otv => otv.LanguageId,
                            l => l.ID, (otv, l) => new LangCodeValues
                            {
                                LangCode = l.Code,
                                LangValue = otv.Value
                            }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: What version of EF core are you using? As for tips - start from checking out the generated SQL

Comment: Can't you do this by using the navigation properties and includes, without explicit joins?

Comment: Why do you have the `.ToList()` in your `Join` expression.  Wouldn't that cause the join to happen in client memory rather than on the server?  It's often times easier to debug these things by having intermediate variables so that you can see the types of the variables and look at the generated SQL

Comment: @Flydog No, this secong ToList() is "attached" to LangValues which is IEnumerable property of class CmsOtherTranslationsView. I dont know to how to get rid of this...

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes I could, but how?

Comment: @GuruStron EF Core 5.0.9. How can i check generated SQL?

Comment: But, isn't `context.OtherTranslationsValues  .Where(row => row.OtherTranslationId == x.ID)  .Join(context.Languages, otv => otv.LanguageId,  l => l.ID, (otv, l) => new LangCodeValues  {  LangCode = l.Code,  LangValue = otv.Value  }` just another queryable?  Don't materialize it to an IEnumerable, keep it in queryable land and let the EF magic do its thing server-side

Comment: I'm assuming this works in Core (it does in the Framework).  To see the generated SQL, have an intermediate variable that represents the query (i.e., right before your `.ToList` call  (`var intermediate = context.EF_Stuff`).  Then call `.ToList` on that variable (`var u = intermediate.ToList()`).  Put a breakpoint right _after_ the `.ToList` call (i.e., once the query has been materialized).  At that point, you should see the SQL if you examine the `intermediate` variable in the debugger

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, thats great idea, but already tested. Got this:The query contains a projection 'x => DbSet<OtherTranslationsValue>()
    .Where(row => row.OtherTranslationId == x.ID)
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Language>(), 
        outerKeySelector: otv => otv.LanguageId, 
        innerKeySelector: l => l.ID, 
        resultSelector: (otv, l) => new LangCodeValues{ 
            LangCode = l.Code, 
            LangValue = otv.Value 
        }

Comment: )' of type 'IQueryable<LangCodeValues>'. Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable<T>' type such as 'List<T>'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to convert the 'IQueryable<T>' or 'IOrderedEnumerable<T>' into an 'IEnumerable<T>'.

Comment: @Flydog57 Since LangValues is type of public IEnumerable<LangCodeValues> LangValues { get; set; }

Comment: See  [Difference using joins or navigation properties in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481217/difference-using-joins-or-navigation-properties-in-ef) and many other posts relating to [ef core navigation properties vs joins](https://www.google.com/search?q=ef+core+navigation+properties+vs+joins).

Comment: @jskorups, you have cartesian explosion of records. Too much I think. Maybe better rethink for which purpose this data is needed?

Comment: @Flydog57 I got this query:  SELECT [o].[ID], [o].[TranslationCode], [t].[LangCode], [t].[LangValue], [t].[ID], [t].[ID0]
FROM [OtherTranslations] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [l].[Code] AS [LangCode], [o0].[Value] AS [LangValue], [o0].[ID], [l].[ID] AS [ID0], [o0].[OtherTranslationId]
    FROM [OtherTranslationsValue] AS [o0]
    INNER JOIN [Languages] AS [l] ON [o0].[LanguageId] = [l].[ID]
) AS [t] ON [o].[ID] = [t].[OtherTranslationId]
ORDER BY [o].[ID], [t].[ID], [t].[ID0]

Comment: @Flydog If I remove last line: ORDER BY [o].[ID], [t].[ID], [t].[ID0]   it wokrs smooth, but i dont know how to link this with linq query...

Comment: @Flydog I belive its because this first .ToList() its grouping and ordering as class demands...

Comment: Download LinqPad (https://www.linqpad.net/).  It can make figuring this stuff out a lot easier.

Comment: As I know from EF Core and it's Eager Loading, you can do here nothing. Too much records.

Comment: Can you please share how many records each of your tables has? Is there really no where clause in the outer query (OtherTranslations)?